# Find inferred type for local function

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ghci

Is there a way in ghci (or ghc) to find what the inferred type of a local function is?

E.g. if I have a function

```
f l = map f' l
   where f' = (+1)
```

is there a `:t`-like way in ghci to see what the inferred type for `f'` is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any way of doing it from GHCi.

However, if you're using an editor like Emacs or Vim, you can try [ghc-mod](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/). This is an external tool that plugs into an editor and gives you some IDE-like functionality for Haskell programs, including the ability to get the type of an arbitrary expression, including a local definition.

In Emacs, you would use `C-c C-t` to find the type of an expression.

If you're not using Emacs or Vim, you could probably wrap ghc-mod as a GHCi extension or something, but I think that would be somewhat awkward. I can't imagine a good way to do it without having an editor-like UI. However, ghc-mod itself is just a standalone command-line tool, so it's easy to work with. If you can think of a good user interface for it that's independent of an existing text editor, go for it!

Of course, if you're not using Emacs or Vim, you probably should :P.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it working, but this looks amazing!

Answer (score 8):

Indeed there is, which I learned about thanks to hammar's awesome answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9987969/176841). Here's the short version:

```
Prelude> :l /tmp/foo.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/foo.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :break f
Breakpoint 0 activated at /tmp/foo.hs:(1,1)-(2,18)
*Main> f [1..10]
Stopped at /tmp/foo.hs:(1,1)-(2,18)
_result :: [b] = _
[/tmp/foo.hs:(1,1)-(2,18)] *Main> :step
Stopped at /tmp/foo.hs:1:7-14
_result :: [b] = _
f' :: b -> b = _
l :: [b] = _
[/tmp/foo.hs:1:7-14] *Main> :t f'
f' :: b -> b
```

Comment: This only shows the type of `f'` in terms of type variables, which I assume doesn't completely answer the OP's question. You can go a step further with `:print f'` which will force the evaluation of `f'`. Then `:t f'` will show the concrete type.

Comment: This is intriguing, I can't get the full type, even with @Code-Guru 's note. E.g. in this case it should be `f' :: (Num b) => b -> b`

Comment: Yeah, I'd be interested in an explanation of the nitty-gritty here w/r/t behavior with and without an explicit polymorphic type signature, as well as in presence of extensions like `NoMonomorphismRestriction` and maybe `MonoLocalBinds`. @amindfv what version of GHC are you using?

Comment: @jberryman - I'm got a machine running 7.4.1, and one running 7.0.4.

Comment: @amindfv After a closer look, I see that my original comment was incorrect. `:print f'` doesn't behave as I thought. I suggest that you check out http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html which might have information to answer your quesion.

Answer (score 0):

Try [hdevtools](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hdevtools), it's quite fast and easy to use, though there's only integration for Vim.

Comment: Could you describe how to get the type of an expression with hdevtools?

Comment: hdevtools type file.hs row column